# Need a radius around a latitude and longitude location

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-fql

So I got a FQL query and I got the latitude and longitude of a person.

ex: Latitude: 51.219215899999990000 and Longitude: 4.402881799999932000

Now this is a location and I need like all the events in a radius of 50000 meters around those coordinates.  So I got my FQl query:

```
WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 500 ))  AND start_time>'" + startTime + "' 
    AND start_time<'" + endTime + "' AND venue.latitude < "NEED" 
    AND venue.latitude > "NEED" and venue.longitude < "NEED" 
    AND venue.longitude > "NEED" 
ORDER BY attending_count DESC 
LIMIT 25
```

Everywhere where there is NEED I need to put in coordinates so I get a radius of 50000 meters of the location of the person. How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 0):

One degree of latitude is 111.13 km.

One degree of longitude is 111.32km * cos( latitude ).

Don't forget to convert the latitude to radians when you work out the cosine.  Also, I assume you realise that with the FQL that you're using, you're actually getting a square, not a circle.

Putting all of this together, you can say that the north-south distance between two points (in km) is (difference in latitude) * 111.13 and the east-west distance is (difference in longitude) * 111.32 * cos(latitude in radians).  To ensure that the distance is less than 50km, you use Pythagoras' theorem to get the condition

```
((difference in latitude) * 111.13)^2 + (difference in longitude * 111.32 * cos(latitude in radians))^2 < 2500
```

I don't know whether FQL has trigonometric functions.  If it doesn't, you'll have to work out the cosine outside of the FQL, then build the FQL accordingly.

Comment: Ok thank you. So the thing I want to do is add and subtract 0.33 from longitude and latitude then I get a radius of about 30km around the location?

Comment: Do you know how that I can get a circle instead of a square?

Comment: Don't forget the `cos(latitude)` bit.  It's kind of important, because lines of longitude are much closer together near the poles than near the equator.  Umm, and yes, a circle is easy to deal with.  I'll edit it into the answer.